# Find distance and time for nearby places from current location using Volley

Tags: android, google-api, android-volley

I’m new with android studio. I want to use Volley to retrieve data from the Google server. I use two HTTP URL to search for nearby places and the distance and time from current location. However, I cannot find any method to use Volley for sending two “JSONRequest”. First request for searching nearby places and the second one for distance and time matrix for each nearby places from current location. The distance matrix HTTP URL is depend on the first one to find the nearby places before it can be executed. Is there any method to search nearby places with distance and time using single HTTP URL?

Or other method to use Volley for multiple request?

Your help is appreciated.

Here the Code I'm Using:

```
private int PROXIMITY_RADIUS = 5000; //5.0KM
private String NAME = "emergency";// emergency+hospital
private String TYPE = "hospital";

private String googlePlacesData;
private String googleDistData;
private Places placeJsonParser = new Places();

public List<PlaceData> searchNearby(double latitude, double longitude)
        throws Exception{

    List<PlaceData> googlePlacesList = new ArrayList<>();

    try {

        StringBuilder googlePlacesUrl = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
        googlePlacesUrl.append("location=" + latitude + "," + longitude);
        //googlePlacesUrl.append("&radius=" + PROXIMITY_RADIUS);
        googlePlacesUrl.append("&rankby=distance");
        googlePlacesUrl.append("&name=" + NAME);
        googlePlacesUrl.append("&type=" + TYPE);
        googlePlacesUrl.append("&sensor=true");
        googlePlacesUrl.append("&key=" + GOOGLE_API_KEY);

        if (googlePlacesUrl.length() > 0)
            System.out.println("Exist GooglePlacesURL: " + googlePlacesUrl.toString());

        Http http = new Http();
        googlePlacesData = http.read(googlePlacesUrl.toString());
        googlePlacesList = placeJsonParser.parse(new JSONObject(googlePlacesData));

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return googlePlacesList;
}

public List<PlaceData> distanceMatrix(List<PlaceData> googlePlace,GPSTracker gps){

    List<PlaceData> googlePlacesDistTimeList = new ArrayList<>();

    try {

    StringBuilder googleDistTimeURL = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?");
    googleDistTimeURL.append("origins=" + gps.getLatitude() + "," + gps.getLongitude());
    googleDistTimeURL.append("&destinations=");

    int counter = 0;

    for (PlaceData place:googlePlace){
        if (counter != (googlePlace.size()-1)){
            googleDistTimeURL.append(place.getLatitude() + "," + place.getLongitude() + "|");
        }else {
            googleDistTimeURL.append(place.getLatitude() + "," + place.getLongitude());
        }
        counter++;
    }
    googleDistTimeURL.append("&key=" + GOOGLE_API_KEY);

    if (googleDistTimeURL.length() > 0)
        System.out.println("Exist GooglePlacesURL: " + googleDistTimeURL.toString());

    Http http = new Http();
    googleDistData = http.read(googleDistTimeURL.toString());
    googlePlacesDistTimeList = placeJsonParser.parseDistTime(new JSONObject(googleDistData),googlePlace);

}catch (Exception e){
    Log.e("Exception", e.toString());
}

    return googlePlacesDistTimeList;
}
```

Comment: It isn't clear to me why two requests are a problem, or exactly what you're looking for in a better solution.

Comment: I want to know is there any better solution to search nearby places with distance and time using Volley